# How to detect if a point is inside complex, irregular vector shape (SVG)?

Tags: svg, events, detection, point, vector-graphics

I'm more or less new to all this. I'm trying to create an app using SVG (as I'd rather have vector shapes that can scale without loss of quality). Using web technologies and would later migrate to react-native.

Is there any way for me to find out if a point (x,y which would also be determined by CSS's *left* and *top* properties) is inside a highly complex, irregular, vector shape?

I know my question is full of constraints, which makes it really hard to answer, even pointing to the right documentation would be helpful.

PS: I tried the method elementFromPoint() but it returns the bounding rectangle which the DOM is putting around my SVG. That completely defeats my purpose, I'd want to make sure the point is only detected within the SVG Paths and shape itself.
Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: So are you trying to detect the point under your cursor to display a hovering effect on the SVG or is it something more complicated? Are you just using an inline SVG or are you using a library like Two.js or D3?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/isPointInFill

Comment: @NickGimbal  Hey, it would be a static point, not the mouse cursor. I was looking to drag a view full of different paths/shapes and see when they intersect the point. No other libraries for now. The term **inline** has been mentioned a couple of times, you guys are referring to the HTML inline versus block? Anyways Thanks very much for responding!

Comment: @Kaiido  Hi, I thought about that but got paranoid that this wouldn't be fully usable across all browsers, thats SVG2 right? Thanks for the post!

Comment: @Sphinxxx Wow I was comparing to the surrounding SVG, not the individual paths within. So incredibly helpful, thank you for the code as well which made it perfectly clear!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as you use inline SVGs, [`elementFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) should work just fine:

```js
const shape = document.querySelector('#shape'),
      status = document.querySelector('#inout');

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    const x = e.clientX,
          y = e.clientY;
    
    if(document.elementFromPoint(x, y) === shape) {
        status.className = status.textContent = 'inside';
    }
    else {
        status.className = status.textContent = 'outside';
    }
});
```

```css
h2 { margin: 0; }

.inside { color: lime; }
.outside { color: red; }
```

```html
<h2>The cursor is: <span id="inout" class="outside">outside</span></h2>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="250" height="200">
    <path id="shape" d="M150,120  q26,75 -80,50  c-80,-25 -53,-125 -26,-125  c53,-25 107,-25 107,50  q107,-50 53,50 z"
          stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" stroke="limegreen" />
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n98m4Lrk/

Comment: Wow I was comparing to the surrounding SVG, not the individual paths within. So incredibly helpful, thank you for the code as well which made it perfectly clear!

Comment: Thanks for the example.. tip top (thumbsup)